# Getting error Http service: NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.”

Tags: angular, typescript

I was using ng-repeat in previous version of angular . It's easy to use. But in newer version Same process isn't working anymore after research i came to know that we need to use ngfor but somehow i'm getting an error. I have searched a lot and got similar questions but in my case nothing worked for me. As i'm new in angular so it's tough to understand. Any kind of help would be highly appreciated. Thank you

This is my typescript :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ShopDetailPage } from '../shopdetail/shopdetail';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-shops',
  templateUrl: 'shops.html'
})

export class ShopsPage {
  shops = {};
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private http: HttpClient){


    http.get('http://192.168.0.3:3000/api/shops').subscribe(
      (data:any) => {

        this.shops = data;
        console.log(data);
      }
    )



    };

}
```

with the help of ng for i want to print the values.

```
<div *ngFor='let shop of shops'>
  <p>{{shop.name}}</p>
</div>
```

here is my .json

```
  [
   {
     "_id": "5b263b2688a9d92e34474e21",
     "image": "eot7wz1wkjiitvz6dmio-amore-logo.png",
     "is_active": "Y",
     "name": "Mio Amore",
     "address": [
  {
    "_id": "5b263b2688a9d92e34474e20",
    "address1": "Post Office Road, \r\nNorth 24 Parganas",
    "address2": " ",
    "city": "Habra",
    "state": "West Bengal",
    "zipcode": "743263",
    "country": "India",
    "geo_lat": "22.8428643",
    "geo_lng": "88.65772400000003",
    "full_address": "Post Office Road, \r\nNorth 24 Parganas, Habra, West Bengal, 743263",
    "__v": 0
  }
],
"__v": 0,
"deleted": false,
"mobile": "033-25225252",
"email": "daraopathikbor@gmail.com"
 },
```

Comment: @kirit kumar saha did you tried my answer on stackblitz.?

Answer (score 1):

Your `data` is not an array, but an object which contains an array. You need to assign to the `this.shops` the array property of the `data`.

Something

```
this.shops = data.shops; // or maybe another name
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your same example working perfect,

I displayed result in app.component.html page,

your sample json missing ] bracket.I just added one ] ending array please check demo here.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gtpiwd

Answer (score -1):

You defined `shops` as an `object`

```
shops = {}; // Object
```

Instead, create an `array`

```
shops = [];
```

Comment: @Dr.KiritKumarSaha can you upvote and accept the answer. downvoter can you explain the reason to downvote?